# How do I read files from language C and save them as strings in memory, get the stored strings and cut them into a specific length? on linux LF format

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, malloc

I want to approach the string as an array, cut it to a specific length, and store it in a two-dimensional array. For example, I have 20 lines of text file. like this "input.txt"

```
www.google.com
www.naver.com
kbphonemall.com
kbplant.com
k-bplus.com
kbpointreestore.com
kbprint.com
kbprism.com
kbprivatebanking.com
kbpstore.com
kbr9rtudaf5ppy.com
kbrafting.com
kbraille.com
kbrainbank.com
kbrainbow.com
kbrainc.com
kbrainglocal.com
kbrandexpo.com
kbrandingschool.com
kbrandmall.com
```

and Then, I read this file and tried to crop it on each line using "\n as the key.
For example If you want to cut four lines at a time, you should cut it to "kbplant.com" first. And the truncated string looks like this.

```
www.google.com\nwww.naver.com\nkbphonemall.com\nkbplant.com\n
```

and It will then be stored in a pointer array. like this

```
char *cutting[n];
cutting[0] = "www.google.com\nwww.naver.com\nkbphonemall.com\nkbplant.com\n"
cutting[1] = "k-bplus.com\nkbpointreestore.com\nkbprint.com\nkbprism.com\n"
.... more
```

So far, that's the explanation of the functions I want to implement and I'll show you the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IPATH "input.txt"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *ListBuffer;
    int ListSize;

    FILE *InputFile = fopen(IPATH, "r");

    fseek(InputFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    ListSize = ftell(InputFile);

    ListBuffer = malloc(ListSize);
    memset(ListBuffer, 0, ListSize);

    fseek(InputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(ListBuffer, ListSize, 1, InputFile);

    int count = 0;
    ListBuffer[ListSize] = '\0'; //add NULL word

    for (int i = 0; i <= ListSize; i++) {
        if (ListBuffer[i] == '\n') {
            count++;
            if (count == 4) {
                printf("c%d\n", i);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (ListBuffer[i] == 0) {
            printf("c%d\n", i);
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(InputFile);
    free(ListBuffer);
    ListBuffer = NULL;
}
```

this is my code I have used various functions such as `strcpy` function, `strtok` function, `memcpy` function, etc., but it was difficult to implement the desired function. Is there a better way or algorithm?

If you need more explanation, I'll answer it quickly.

I would appreciate it if you could reply. Have a good day.

Comment: looks like you clear an N byte size buffer, and then read N bytes into it, so there's no room for a null terminator `'\0'`

Comment: Wonlf, _strings_ denote their length with a terminating _null character_.  It is uncommon, but possible to _read_ a null character.  Storing a line of input as a string (which appends a `'\0'`) then has the problem of the inability to distinguish the read `'\0'` from an appended one.  Perhaps detect this case and treat as an error condition or use a non-string solution.

Comment: Wonlf `ListBuffer[i] != 0` is not going to be false unless a null character was read.  Code will iterate past `ListSize`.  Better as `for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++) {`.

Comment: Wonlf, If the last _line_ of the file lacks a final `'\n'` like `"kbrandmall.com"` instead of `"kbrandmall.com\n"`, what should code do? Detect and error out? Treat that as if it had ended with `'\n'`?

Comment: @Wonlf don't put code in comments, as you can see it's unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you very much for your reply. I listened to your reply and modified the code result is `c56
c112
c179
c233
c300`  i want put in data temp[0] = Listbuffer[0]~[56], temp[1] = Listbuffer[57]~[112].... more what should i do?

Comment: For sure this is a problem: `for (int i = 0; i <= ListSize; i++)` -> `for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++)`

Comment: No, the for loop should go up to 300. If you turn to 299, you can't find the 233~300 index \n because you can't skip the null character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve in the main loop, but there are more problems:

- you must allocate one extra byte to set the null terminator at `ListSize`:

  ListBuffer = malloc(ListSize + 1);
- it is useless to set the array to `0` with `memset`: allocating with `calloc(1, ListSize + 1)` would be more efficient for this purpose, but since you read the contents into the array, clearing it first is useless.
- `fread` might return a short count, for example in text mode on legacy systems, converting CR/LR sequences to newline bytes `\n` reduces the number of bytes read:

  ```
    ListSize = fread(ListBuffer, 1, ListSize, InputFile);
    ListBuffer[ListSize] = '\0'; // set the null terminator
  ```